# Text shadow Inset effect css3

Tags: css, insets

[image]

I want the inset effect for the above button. The 'text' cancel appears to be type pressed.
I have tried a lot of examples available online but they don't have white background examples.

Help me to gain this effect.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With the `text-shadow` property, you should be able to get the subtle effect that you're after:

```
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #888;
```

See a very basic example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5KWAw/).